# Does Grail Controller follows the single responsibility Principle of SOLID?

Tags: java, oop, grails, solid-principles

Currently, I am learning the SOLID Principles. I have some confusion on the SRP (Single Responsibility Principle). While creating a WebApi Controller, we are implementing the CRUD operation within the same controller of the same domain.

Does the controller violate the Single Responsibility Principal of SOLID?

Comment: Without any code, you are talking about, the answer extrapolating from your question is most likey: yes, _your_ controller violates that. Grails auto generated code (and sometimes also the design descicions and docs) focus on the quick result. If you use this features unreflected, don't blame the framework - blame the framework if you dont have any other choice. But here you can just write some different controller code, that just takes a web request and shapes it into the data needed for your services to consume.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the controller violate the Single Responsibility Principal of
>   SOLID?

Not necessarily, no.  The author of the controller gets to decide what logic the controller will include.  A controller could very well be written which violates SRP but that is up to the author.